# which remote Notification certificate do I need to use with Ad-hoc

Tags: ios

I'm wondering what kind of Remote notification (APN) certificate do I need to use with Ad-hoc, development or production?

I was expecting I would need to use the production one, but surprisingly it worked with development.

Now, the issue with this, is how I'm going to make sure if I correctly generated the production APN certificate, if there is no way to test except when the app go live.

Comment: Are you meaning that you install an Ad-hoc version with iTunes and development APN certificate DOES work? That is very rare. Something wrong, I think.

Comment: Yes, I install ad-hoc, and on server side, I used development certificate. it worked.

Comment: perhaps you are signing ad-hoc with developer certificate?

Comment: Yes, I believe so. I will sign it again with ad-hoc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From Apple's documentation

> "apps distributed via ad-hoc use the apple production push gateway (gateway.push.apple.com),
>   not the apple dev push gateway"

For adhoc builds use SSL certificate for production and not for development.